# Slick Carousel not animating. All slide content shows at once without navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slideshow, slick.js

JS noob here. I'm sorry if the answer is obvious, but I can't figure out why my slick carousel won't load. I've tried everything I can think of, but I'm at a loss. Please help me! Also, any recommended crash courses to understand the basics better would help greatly.

```
    



jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
  jQuery(".slickshow").slick({
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    slide: '.slide',
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    dots: true,
    prevArrow: '&#10094',
    nextArrow: '&#10095',
    speed: 1000,
    fade: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    swipe: true,
    swipeToSlide: true,
    infinite: true
  });
});
// On swipe event
jQuery('.slickshow').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction) {
  console.log(direction);
  // left
});
// On edge hit
jQuery('.slickshow').on('edge', function(event, slick, direction) {
  console.log('edge was hit')
});
// On before slide change
jQuery('.slickshow').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  console.log(nextSlide);
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<section class="slickshow carousel">
  <!--slide-->
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500?text=Placeholder+Image">
    <h2>SUMMERTIME SAVINGS</h2>
    <p>100s of Items On Sale!</p>
    <p><a href="#">Shop the Sale Now!</a></p>
  </div>
  <!--slide-->
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500?text=Another+One">
  </div>
  <!--slide-->
  <div class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500?text=Placeholder+Image">
    <h2>MORE SAVINGS</h2>
    <p>More Text Too!</p>
    <p><a href="#">Shop Now</a></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think was you `prevArrow` and `nextArrow` values.

I've also added the SLICK SLIDER css in the `<head>`.

From the docs reference https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```
string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery object)
<button type="button" class="slick-prev">Previous</button>
Allows you to select a node or customize the HTML for the "Previous" arrow.
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
<!-- Slick slider css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
    <section class="slickshow carousel">
    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500?text=Placeholder+Image">
      <h2>SUMMERTIME SAVINGS</h2>
      <p>100s of Items On Sale!</p>
      <p><a href="#">Shop the Sale Now!</a></p>
    </div>
    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500?text=Another+One">
    </div>
    <!--slide-->
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1440x500?text=Placeholder+Image">
      <h2>MORE SAVINGS</h2>
      <p>More Text Too!</p>
      <p><a href="#">Shop Now</a></p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(".slickshow").slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        slide: '.slide',
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        dots: true,
        // string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery object)
        prevArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next">&#10094</button>',
        nextArrow: '<button type="button" class="slick-next">&#10095</button>',
        speed: 1000,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        swipe: true,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        infinite: true
      });
    });
    // On swipe event
    jQuery('.slickshow').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction) {
      console.log(direction);
      // left
    });
    // On edge hit
    jQuery('.slickshow').on('edge', function(event, slick, direction) {
      console.log('edge was hit')
    });
    // On before slide change
    jQuery('.slickshow').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
      console.log(nextSlide);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```